# Select children where not within container jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This would seem like an easy problem but I am having some trouble figuring this one out. The example given is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and I have a larger problem that this attempts to solve. In order for this to work the query must NOT contain any immediate child selectors (`>`) due to the dom tree being a bit more complex than this example.

My goal here is to select all children whom aren't underneath a parent who contains a class. In this example I am trying to select the 2 div containers `hello` and `world` but not `foo` and `bar`.

Here is a plunker that has the code in it for your convience. http://plnkr.co/edit/4zsKAFts5X7X2kLADj2V?p=preview

---

Using this HTML:

```
<div id="root" class="parent">
  <div>
    <div class="child">hello</div>
    <div class="child">world</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div>
      <div class="child">foo</div>
      <div class="child">bar</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this Javascript:

```
var root = $('#root');
$(':not(.parent) .child', root).css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

---

I am seeing this result:

> **hello**
>
> **world**
>
> **foo**
>
> **bar**

But what I would like to get is

> **hello**
>
> **world**
>
> foo
>
> bar

---

To reiterate I want to get all elements with class `child` who dont have a parent with class `parent` starting from a given node (in this example `#root`).

Comment: `I want to get all elements with class child who dont have a parent with class parent` The root has the `parent` class, so I'm not sure how you're expecting this work?

Comment: I guess I would like to restrict the query to the given node, in this case `root`

Comment: As you stipulated "Starting from a given node", you should go with a version that takes a root node as a parameter and not use a hard-wired selector constant e.g.: `var root = $('#root');
$('.child',  root).not(root.find(".parent .child")).css('font-weight', 'bold');` or `$('.child',  root).not($(".parent .child",root)).css('font-weight', 'bold');`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie well this is just a small example I made up to show the problem I was having, my actual code really looks nothing like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var root = $('#root');
$('.child',  root).not($("#root .parent .child")).css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yX3ym/)**

Comment: Why are you making and jQuery object inside the `.not()`? Anyway, probably the best solution. +1

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - Lazy I guess ;) Anyway, you could also do `.not($(".parent .child",root))`

Comment: Cool. Works for any situation I threw at it :)

Comment: I would suggest a slight change so that the root selector is not referenced twice, as that will not be as portable as referencing the `root` var instead (see below).

Answer (score 1):

It might not be pretty but here you go:

```
$('#root').find('.child').filter(function(){
    if($(this).parents('.parent').first().attr('id') === 'root'){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}).css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/PDZL8/**

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie idk who upvoted me but my tests reveal that you are right. I am working on a working solution lol

Comment: What about `.closest()` instead of a combination of `.parents` and `.first()`? :)

Comment: You don't need the `if/else`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie why won't it work? Please modify my fiddle to illustrate

Comment: Retracted comment... it checks for first `.parent` from bottom up.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I see, I fixed the if/else as well

Comment: non-portable idea to reference the root in two different ways ('#root' and 'root'). Try use a local var like the original

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/78G6N/3/

```
var root = $('#root');
$('#root').find('.child').filter(function(){
    return $(this).closest('.parent').is(root);
}).css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

I also improved j08691's solution so that it uses the root node supplied, rather than duplicating the selector (which is not portable):

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/78G6N/4/

```
var root = $('#root');
$('.child',  root).not(root.find(".parent .child")).css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

Comment: Just a little optimisation, you could do `is(root)` instead of a not + length + bang.

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon: Ah.. I had a typo in that version. Thanks. Updated to your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
$('#root').find('.child').filter(function(){
    return $(this).parents('.parent').length <= 1;
}).css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

It check the number of parent the div has and if it is lower or equal than 1, it return the child.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/akwPb/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I really don't see what you mean. `.parents()` will only select element with the class `parent` So it doesnt matter if there is more div's.

Comment: If you add a .parent above the current structure it will fail: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/akwPb/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#root .child:not(#root .parent * .child)")
    .css("font-weight", "bold")
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/UJJXU/

Comment: "Starting from a given node" implies the `#root` should not be a hard-wired selector string, but used as a parameter.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Are not all jQuery selectors , in essence , "selector string"'s ? Does not above piece "start from" `#root` "node" `$("#root .child . .`? Not exactly certain how above piece appear different than other Answers posted , save for omission of `.find()` and `.filter()` . Please illuminate . Thanks